# using node-sass instead of sass

Tags: javascript, sass, node-sass

I mean this question a genuine curiosity.

If you're using `node`, `npm` (or `yarn`) and you have a `package.json` with scripts that you can tell your CI to run to build your application/put together your assets, what is the reasoning behind choosing to implement `node-sass` over `sass`?

What would the reasons be to put your styles through your JS runtime? (That's what I understand it would be doing, I guess that's likely off by a mile)

Answer (score 1):

`node-sass` is simply bindings to `libsass` so that JavaScript tools can call it. This is particularly essential for bundling tools like `webpack` which are written in JavaScript.

Comment: sure, but why would you need to run your styles through `webpack` (assuming you're running a script to do it), if you could do the same with the `sass` cli? Is it convenience? Or perhaps there are specific use cases (not bundling) that require Sass to be tied into JS?

Comment: You don't _need_ to, but the webpack `sass-loader` enables all kinds of things, like importing `.scss` files in your JavaScript code, CSS splitting that works hand-in-hand with JavaScript code splitting, unified asset file management, etc. If you look into the webpack ecosystem (or other JS toolchains that use `node-sass`) you see how there are many useful things you can do with style-aware JavaScript. If you _only_ want to manually generate CSS files using sass, go for it.